# Testing Yii REST application using a second database

Tags: php, yii2, codeception

I wrote an API using Yii2 and following [the REST guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html). My API is working and I want to write some tests for it, so I once again followed [the guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-test-overview.html) on how to run tests and got unit tests working. I then looked around Codeception documentation about [testing WebServices](http://codeception.com/docs/10-WebServices) and got this working too.

My problem is that API calls are not using my test database. I have two databases, one called `db` and the other `testdb`. Here is my `config.php` file in `tests/codeception/config/`:

```
return [
    'components' => [
        'db' => [
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;port=8889;dbname=testdb;unix_socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'showScriptName' => true,
        ],
    ],
];
```

I wrote a simple test that send a GET request to an endpoint to retrieve data. My test database is empty so I am expecting to receive an empty response, but I get the content of my other database instead.

I then tried to set `YII_ENV` to `test` as described in the Environment Constant section [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-configurations.html) so that I could test against the env variable `YII_ENV_TEST` and change the `db` configuration accordingly. I tried to set this variable in the `_bootstrap.php` file in the `tests/codeception/` folder:

```
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'test');
```

I then logged the value of `YII_ENV` in the `web/index.php` file (`index-test.php` is not called, might be a problem too), and it is undefined.

What am I doing wrong? I tried including the `Yii2` module in my `api.suite.yml` file but requests don't have return code anymore if I do that, it returns `N/A`. Is there another way to change which database Yii should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a "solution" by using this other app template: https://github.com/githubjeka/yii2-rest

The file organization fits my needs better and I can easily configure which database to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an test_config.php file and at the end of the config place this

```
if (file_exists('protected/config/test_config.php'))
{    
    include 'test_config.php';
}
```

the file will be included if it exists. And the file test_config.php should contain the overwritten value for the db connection.

Hope this helps! 
Keep on coding! 
Ares.

Comment: How do you suggest creating this file? In the `_bootstrap.php` script? Feels a bit like a hack to me... Anyway I found another solution, thanks!

Comment: You create the file in the config folder, and call it in db.php :D